# statcounter custom tag for pop-up page

Tags: jquery-plugins, modal-dialog, analytics

i have a list of products in my web page whose details are shown in modal popup.
I tried using the *custom tag* of **statcounter** as shown on their site [http://statcounter.com/support/knowledge-base/276/] **but it works only for one product category.** I am using the same modal body to show different products.
following is the codesnippet :

```
 var sc_project = $#@$#@;
    var sc_invisible = 0;
    var sc_security = "$#*$*##$";
    var _statcounter = _statcounter || [];
    //function to push custom statcounter for products_of_interest
    function _productStatCounter(product_of_interest) {
        _statcounter.push({ "tags": { "data-project": product_of_interest } });
    }
   // jquery to push projects based on click 
        $(".portfolio-link").click(function () {
            test_product = ($(this).attr("href"));
            if(test_product !== undefined){
                product_of_interest = ($(this).attr("data-project"));
                _productStatCounter(product_of_interest);

            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
```

I used jquery to push the product_of_interest based on click of the product but statcounter is showing info about only one product not all the products. Since my product web app is a single page so i have used modal-body for showing different products on a popup screen. Is there any way to use statcounter on popups ?

Comment: Well finally i found the solution. It is a "trick" which i used to achieve my Goal. Well the solution goes like this. First I made a separate Html page Which has the StatCounter Code then using Jquery on the PopUp i Dynamically added a hidden Iframe (which has the source of the statcounter html page). Then i dynamically set the "product_of_interest"  in that html page.  Thus statcounter can be used on popups page using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. My window's hash changes when I open a modal and I was able to push the tags to statcounter on hash change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var sc_project = ******;
        var sc_invisible = 1;
        var sc_click_stat = 2; /*track anchor links*/
        var sc_security = '******';
        var _statcounter = _statcounter || [];
        _statcounter.push({ tags: { page: 'homepage' } });  /*optional*/
        window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
        function locationHashChanged() {
            var modalName = window.location.hash;
            _statcounter.push({ tags: { project: modalName } });
            _statcounter.record_pageview(); 
        }
    </script>
```